# What is this type of differential equation called?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It has a form of $$ \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = -ay(t) + bx(t) .$$

And what's a general formula used to get the solution, or if I can get a link to some texts about this somewhere.

Comment: Linear differential equation.

Comment: This is a first order, linear differential equation in $y(t)$. There is a general solution method, and it should be covered in any introductory differential equations text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *linear inhomogeneous differential equation of first order*. *First order* because the highest derivative is of grade $1$. *Linear* because $y$ and its derivatives appear as linear (and not quadratic or anything else) terms. *Inhomogeneous* because there is an explicit dependence on the variable $x$.

So much for the classification. The method to solve those is to first solve the homogeneous equation ($y' = -ay$) by *separation of variables* and then find a specific solution to the inhomogeneous equation by a method called *variation of constants*. You find examples and general solutions in any introductory textbook on ODE's.

A last remark: There is no need to write $bx(t)$, instead you can just write $x(t)$ and pull the constant $b$ into the function.